# Send email to customers without an attached payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

In my system a Stripe customer is created when a user signs up. The system has a free trial where the credit card is required. But since the creation of the customer happens before the user is able to add their credit card information, some of the users leave when they see the credit card formular.

I would like to send an email-reminder to these users to update their payment methods to get the free trial if the customer has not attached any payment method within the first X days after the creation. I have the customer created in Stripe, their email, address, name etc. It's about 50 customers per week, so it is too much to do this manually. I need some sort of trigger mechanism.

I have been looking for a solution with webhooks or native in Stripe, but it seems like these are only triggered after adding a payment method or creating a customer.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> if the customer has not attached any payment method within the first X days after the creation

Stripe doesn't do anything specific here. You'll have to set up some sort of cron job on your end which looks at when you created Customers and whether they have attached PaymentMethods or not. And if not, then send out reminder emails to them (outside of Stripe).